# How to Launch Spark 2.0 on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

With the release of Spark 2.0 today they have removed native support for launching a Spark EC2 cluster on AWS:

https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#removals-behavior-changes-and-deprecations

> Spark EC2 script has been fully moved to an external repository hosted
>   by the UC Berkeley AMPLab

On the AMPLab GitHub page it includes these instructions:

https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0#launching-a-cluster

> Go into the ec2 directory in the release of Apache Spark you
>   downloaded.

The problem is there is no ec2 folder in the 2.0 download. Anyone know how I can launch a Spark 2.0 cluster in EC2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go into ec2 directory means the directory where you downloaded the Apache Spark from github.

Comment: @error2007s the issue is that there is no ec2 directory in Spark 2.0.0. The instructions in the UC Berkeley AMPLab link provided is very unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**LAST EDIT**

For anyone having this issue, the answer is simpler: [here](https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0).

**EDIT 2**

I realized after first edit that it is slightly more convoluted, so here's a new edit about for anyone that might find it useful in the future.

The issue is that Spark does no longer provide the ec2 directory as part of the official distribution. If you're used to spinning up your standalone clusters this way it is an issue.

The solution is simple:

1. Download the official ec2 directory as detailed in the Spark 2.0.0 documentation.
2. If you just copy the dir to your Spark 2.0.0 and run the `spark-ec2` executable to mimic the way things worked in Spark 1.*, you will be able to spin up your cluster as usual. But when you ssh into it you'll realize that none of the binaries are there anymore.
3. So, once you spin up your cluster (as you normally would with the `spark-ec2` you downloaded in step 1), you'll have to `rsync` your local directory containing Spark 2.0.0 into the master of your newly created cluster. Once this is done, you can `spark-submit` jobs as you normally do.

Really simple but it seems to me the Spark docs could be clear about this for all of us normies.

---

**EDIT:** This was in fact the right thing to do. For anyone having the same question: download the ec2 dir from AMPLab like Spark suggests, put this folder inside your local Spark-2.0.0 dir, and fire-up scripts as usual. Apparently they only decoupled the directory for maintenance purposes, but the logic is still the same. Would be nice to have a few words about it in the Spark docs.

---

I tried the following: cloned the spark-ec2-branch-1.6 directory from the AMPLab link into my spark-2.0.0 directory, and attempted to launch a cluster with the usual `./ec2/spark-ec2` command. Maybe that's what they want us to do?

I'm launchng a small 16 node cluster. I can see it in the AWS dashboard but the terminal has been stuck printing the usual SSH error for the past... almost two hours.

`Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-54-165-25-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: ssh: connect to host ec2-54-165-25-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused`

Will update if I find anything useful.

Comment: I did what you suggested with the difference being I used  https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0. Thanks.

Comment: This is so confusing.  There is no `ec2` directory in either branch, `branch-1.6` or `branch-2.0`.  Is the former `ec2` directory now the **root** directory of https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0 ?

Comment: Just added https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/issues/89.  Let's hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: I think you are better off using [Flintrock](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock), which I wrote as the spiritual successor to spark-ec2. I spent a good amount of time [contributing](https://github.com/apache/spark/commits?author=nchammas) to spark-ec2 and decided it would be better to just write a new tool that's faster and more user-friendly.

Answer (score 6):

[Amplab Spark-ec2](https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0) is no longer maintained according to their github repo page. You can create spark cluster using [flintrock](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock) instead on [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: I have used flintrock. It has solved my problem. But do you have a script which allows one to install Ganglia on the cluster? Ganglia is important for cluster monitoring. Having an easy way to install Ganglia would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to download all sources from [here](https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0). Notice that I have provided the 2.0 github branch. Instructions on how to run may be found on the previous link and [here](https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/how-to-set-apache-spark-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-in-a-few-simple-steps-d29f0d6f1a81#.c67ss6n55) is a blog post I wrote about the subject that may simplify your life.

Hope I have managed to help! :)